# Backup recovery partition of windows 8 in GPT

Tags: backup, windows-8, dd, gpt

My friend have acer Laptop which had windows 8 pre installed and a recovery partition(SDA 7).
 He want to use only windows 8 but wants to make a backup of his recovery partition(sda 7) since "recovery is the only way to install win 8 because its product key is in bios"(Told by cusomer care person).
 His drive is GPT. I want to know how to back up sda7 and restore in case of drive failure or something else.

edit
booting in uefi

Answer (score 0):

Well one thing you can do is image the partition using `dd`. Create a Bootable Ubuntu USB/CD and Boot from it(Make sure you choose the "Try" option). Then just open a terminal window in Ubuntu and do the following:

1. List the available partitions on your internal drive

   ```
   fdisk -l | grep sda
   ```
2. Once you've made sure of which Partition is the Recovery Partition(ex: /dev/sda7) you can now use `dd` to backup the partion:

   ```
   sudo dd if=/dev/sda7 of=/location/to/save/the/image/Recovery-Backup.dd bs=1m
   ```

Now in the future you can restore the partition if you ever need to.

Comment: as I mentioned, the drive uses GPT, fdisk -l won't work here, moreover a similar partition table needs to be created in other drive. In mbr its first 512 bytes but i dont know about GPT